# Dial multiple numbers programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a feature for an app where I can call multiple numbers one by one automatically. By a button click a call will be generated to a number,If the call is attended, then break the process there.

If the dialed number is not able to connect the call(by any reason like:

The dialed number busy.
The dialed number is switched off.
The dialed number is in out of coverage area....etc).
Then how can i redirect the call to the another number automatically by checking the call state..?

Whether it is possible to call multiple numbers one by one automatically by checking the state of an outgoing call.., How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by using broadcast receiver and

```
package bp;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.NumberModel;

public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName() + "Atiar - ";
    public  boolean prevState = false, currentState = false;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            // Outgoing call
            final String outgoingCallNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.i(TAG, outgoingCallNumber);
        }

        else {
            // Incoming call
            String incomingCallNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.i(TAG, incomingCallNumber+"");
        }

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //BP.savePreviousState(false);


            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Received State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                BP.savePreviousState(true);
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                currentState=true;

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 100ms
                        Log.e(TAG, "Ideal state");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Idle State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG,"curr = " + currentState + " prev = "+BP.getPreviousState()+ " size ="+ BP.queue.size());
                        if (BP.getPreviousState() && currentState  && BP.queue.size()>0){

                            BP.callNumberFromNumberDialActivity();
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000);


            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

another class with static method and queue and handeler for time delay
package bp;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Queue;

import info.atiar.prnappdialer.NumberDialActivity;

public class BP {
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "pref";
    public static Activity numberDialActivity;
    public static Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public static String getCurrentDateTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        return currentDateandTime;
    }

    public static void openDialPad(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void callNumber(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
        numberDialActivity = activity;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void callNumberFromNumberDialActivity() {
        callNumber(numberDialActivity,queue.remove());
    }

    public static void savePreviousState(Boolean previousState){
            setPreference("prev",previousState);
    }

    public static boolean getPreviousState(){
            return getPreference("prev");
    }


    //SharedPreferences
    private static boolean setPreference(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences settings = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    private static boolean getPreference(String key) {
        SharedPreferences settings = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return settings.getBoolean(key, false);
    }

    private static void removeSingleItem(String keyToRemove) {
        SharedPreferences settings = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().remove(keyToRemove).commit();
    }

    private static void removeAllItem() {
        SharedPreferences settings = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

stock all your numbers in an array and browse this last, if you have N numbers the code java will be

```
for (i=0,i<N,i++)
{test=this.call(A[i]);
  if test==0 i=i+1;
     else i=N;
}
```

A is the array that contains the numbers and ( int call) is the function that call a number and returns 0 if the call fails and 1 if the call is connected, i take the case when just one number success to connect the void stop

Comment: i'm not looking for the logic. I'm looking for the situation, that is it possible by android or not? if possible then how to manage that situation.

Comment: yeah its possible just imagine an app that do what you do exactly when you use the phone app on android : calling, checking if the number is available and cutting the call and triying another number, you can easily coding these

Comment: but how do i know the states? when call ended or canceled or something else?

Comment: here I can't help you, you need a telecom expert because this is out of the phone operating system, i'm sure there is a way but just a telecom programer can help you

Answer (score -1):

try to do while loop for browsing your array of numbers

```
while (i<=N)
{.....}
```

this is more efficient to go on with an Java array